# Order of growth of sequence $f_{n} = 2f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$

Tags: generating-functions, recursion

I'm currently stuck with the following problem.
How do I calculate the order of growth of the following sequence:

$f_{n} = 2f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$

Assuming that

$f_{0} =1$
and $f_{1} = 1$

I've got the following hints:
they used $(1- 2x - x^2) = (1-Ax)(1-Bx) $
to get the roots of the solution.

How do I get from the squence to $(1-2x-x^2)$ and why do I have to equal it to $(1-Ax)(1-Bx)$

Somehow the solution is $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$

Thanks for your help community

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process 1:

Start with $1-2x-x^2$. Now, the given, from the problem, is that 
\begin{align}
1-2x-x^2 &= (1- a x)(1 - b x) \\
&= 1 -(a+b) x + ab x^2.
\end{align}
Equating coefficients leads to $a + b = 2$ and $ab = -1$. Using this information leads to
\begin{align}
a - \frac{1}{a} &= 2 \\
a^2 - 2 a - 1 &= 0 \\
a &= 1 \pm \sqrt{2}. 
\end{align}
By choosing $a = 1 + \sqrt{2}$ then $b$ becomes $b = 1 - \sqrt{2}$. 
Since $f_{n}$ increases with $n$ then consider a solution of the form
$$f_{n} = A \, (1+\sqrt{2})^{n} + B \, (1-\sqrt{2})^{n}$$
With $f_{0} = 1$ and $f_{1} = 1$, then it can be found that $A = B = \frac{1}{2}$ and 
$$f_{n} = \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ (1+\sqrt{2})^{n} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{n} \right].$$

Now, in terms of growth of $f_{n}$, the following is noticed. It can be determined that $0 \leq 1-\sqrt{2} \leq -1$ and $3 \leq 1 + \sqrt{2} \geq 1$. Taking powers of these values leads to $|(1-\sqrt{2})^{n}| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $(1+\sqrt{2})^{n} \to \infty$. This leads to
$$f_{n} \approx (1+\sqrt{2})^{n} $$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What if I didnt have the hint (1-2x-x^2) how do I get there from the sequence?

Comment: @Fill In that case solve the difference equation. Typically try a solution of the form $f_{n} \approx r^{n}$ and solve the resulting equation. For a second order difference equation $r$ will satisfy a quadratic equation.

Comment: is there another way if I don't know how to solve differential equations? Thanks a lot.